# JSON en mi tabla php

Tags: php, json

tengo una tabla la cuan me trae algunos registros.
Mi problema es que el archivo json viene con varios registros ejemplo:

Este es solo un registro, el cual todo esta completo:
[
{

```
    "alias": "Prueba",
    "username": "adminallie",
    "estatus": "Completa",
    "motivo": "NULL",
    "idMovil": 37368,
    "grupo": "31e3b1aa-07c1-4c97-9473-3402d1b3aa83",
    "capturas": [
        {
            "id": 63782,
            "codigoQr64": null,
            "tieneCodigo": true,
            "separadorColumna": ","
        },
        {
            "id": "63783",
            "fotografias": [
                {
                    "fotografia1": "",
                    "url": "Capsulas/af8f04d52dca.jpeg",
                    "descripcion": "",
                    "tieneCoordenada": true,
                    "caracterSeparacion": "|",
                    "caracterSeparacionImg": " ",
                    "defautlValue": "\\,(.*?)\\,",
                    "separadorColumna": ","
                },
               {
                    "fotografia2": "",
                    "url": "Capsulas/54b49f236bdf.jpeg",
                    "descripcion": "",
                    "tieneCoordenada": true,
                    "caracterSeparacion": "|",
                    "caracterSeparacionImg": " ",
                    "defautlValue": "\\,(.*?)\\,",
                    "separadorColumna": ","
                }
            ]
        }
```

]

después de ese viene otro registro el cuan no tiene la segunda fotografía;

[
{

```
    "alias": "Prueba",
    "username": "adminallie",
    "estatus": "Completa",
    "motivo": "NULL",
    "idMovil": 37368,
    "grupo": "31e3b1aa-07c1-4c97-9473-3402d1b3aa83",
    "capturas": [
        {
            "id": 63782,
            "codigoQr64": null,
            "tieneCodigo": true,
            "separadorColumna": ","
        },
        {
            "id": "63783",
            "fotografias": [
                {
                    "fotografia1": "",
                    "url": "Capsulas/af8f04d52dca.jpeg",
                    "descripcion": "",
                    "tieneCoordenada": true,
                    "caracterSeparacion": "|",
                    "caracterSeparacionImg": " ",
                    "defautlValue": "\\,(.*?)\\,",
                    "separadorColumna": ","
                }
            ]
        }
```

]
y solo me marca error ; [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

Como puedo hacer si no esta la segunda fotografía me diga sin registro y lo muestre en la tabla

Answer (score 0):

El json no me parece que siga una estructura clara, pero voy a intentar ayudarte.
El elemento capturas es un array, cuyo segundo elemento es el que tiene un campo fotografías. Voy a dar por hecho que siempre existe, si no deberías comprobarlo.

```
//Compruebo cuantos elementos fotografías hay
//He nombrado a la variable que contiene el json: $json
if($json['capturas'][1]["fotografias"].length == 2){
    //Si entro aquí es que hay dos fotografías
} else {
    //Si entro aquí es que no hay segunda fotografía
}
```

Aun así, este código es suponiendo muchas cosas, ya que no indicas que campos pueden existir y cuales no, si puede haber más de dos fotografías, etc.
Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias Marc N, lo voy a intentar .